# C | Pointer | Segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

I have this code:

My problem is that, whenever I call this function `ma_init();` I get a segmentation fault on `footer->status = FREE`; I would appreciate it if somebody points me into the right direction here cause after some googling for some hours, I can't seem to figure this out.

Edit: header file:

Comment: your `size size;` cannot hold the acutal size, because the number is too large for it.

Comment: What's the type of `mem_chunk_header::size`? Shouldn't that be `size_t`?

Comment: @dhke I just adjusted it in the question. I forgot adding this into the question. Sorry.  `size size`is of type `int`.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) then **use the debugger** (`gdb` )

Comment: What are the units of `header->size`? It looks like you're assuming bytes. But if you have a pointer to `mem_chunk_header` and add an integer to it, the compiler will implicitly multiply that integer by the size of the type the pointer points to. So, `header + header->size + sizeof(mem_chunk_header)` is really (considering it as a pointer to bytes), `header + (header->size + sizeof(mem_chunk_header))* sizeof(mem_chunk_header)) `

Comment: @Bobby - this is a prime example of what should be simple logic -- made wholly unreadable by hiding types behind `typedefs`. You do have an `#endif` at the end of the header don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> typedef unsigned char byte;

This is unreadable. Consider including [`<stdint.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer)  and using `uint8_t`.

> My problem is that, whenever I call this function ma_init(); I get a segmentation fault on footer->status = FREE;

Please learn to compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`) ...

You are initializing `header`  to the address of `mem_pool`.

Then you do some *questionable* (that is **wrong**) [pointer arithmetic](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointer_arithmetic.htm)

```
 mem_chunk_header * footer = header + header->size + sizeof(mem_chunk_header);
 // the + above are likely to be wrong
```

You are adding to a pointer `header` so the `+` is in terms of pointed element size (not bytes), that is in units of `sizeof(mem_chunk_header)` which certainly is at least 2 and probably more (on my Linux/x86-64 desktop it is `8`). Your `footer`  is far away.

With a debugger, you would have noticed that (by querying the values of `header`, `footer`, `mem_pool`). Consider also using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

BTW, if you are coding a [memory allocator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management) à la `malloc` you'll better base it on operating system specific primitives (generally [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call)) modifying your [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space). On Linux you would use [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and friends.

> points me into the right direction here cause after some googling for some hours

You need to spend *weeks* reading some good C programming book. Hours of work are not enough in your case.

Comment: You really need to invest more time, notably learning to use the debugger.